# Use two different Data frame at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, multiple-columns

I have two different data set and want to compare the data set as below;
I have to compare the same x and y at the same time and have x and y in a same data-frame

```
date
    time                   x              
0   1648598400000         233                   
0   1648598400000         234
1   1648598403000         553
2   1648598404000         987
3   1648598405000         732
4   1648598406000         234
5   1648598406000         465

    time                   y
0   1648598400000         6758
1   1648598403000         8678
2   1648598404000         8778
3   1648598405000         4535
4   1648598406000         7656
5   1648598406000         8977
```

Comment: Hi, I think you forgot to set your data as "code", so it isn't very easy to see.  However, if your dataframes are defined as `df1` and `df2`, then you could use the following: `merged_df = df1.merge(df2, left_on="time", right_on="time")`.  This would give you a new dataframe (`merged_df`) with `time` used to match.  See the pandas merge documentation for more detail [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `merge`:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, on='time', how='outer')

            time    x     y
0  1648598400000  233  6758
1  1648598400000  234  6758
2  1648598403000  553  8678
3  1648598404000  987  8778
4  1648598405000  732  4535
5  1648598406000  234  7656
6  1648598406000  234  8977
7  1648598406000  465  7656
8  1648598406000  465  8977
```

Setup I used:

```
>>> df1
            time    x
0  1648598400000  233
0  1648598400000  234
1  1648598403000  553
2  1648598404000  987
3  1648598405000  732
4  1648598406000  234
5  1648598406000  465

>>> df2
            time     y
0  1648598400000  6758
1  1648598403000  8678
2  1648598404000  8778
3  1648598405000  4535
4  1648598406000  7656
5  1648598406000  8977
```